# Creating a surface from 3 vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, surface

I have this [data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B92Nk-QHod5xTk5RdnR2WVRFRTg/view?usp=sharing) file which contains 3 columns. Now, what I am trying to do is create a 3D model which should look something like this.
[image]

I went through couple of posts which I found here and tried to create this model in Matlab but it went wrong. This is what I get.
[image]

Here is the code, which I used to create those models.

```
close all; clear all;

X=xlsread('data.csv', '', 'A:A');
Y=xlsread('data.csv', '', 'B:B');
Z=xlsread('data.csv', '', 'C:C');

[XI YI ZI] = griddata(X,Y,Z,linspace(0,1),linspace(0,1)');

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
trisurf(delaunay(X,Y),X,Y,Z)
subplot(1,2,2);
surf(XI,YI,ZI)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it in order to get a model just like the one above?

**EDIT**

I tried cutting the z plane and this is what I get. I need the planes to be connected. Also I have more data which produce different models so I need a solution which will cover also other models. [image]

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to connect all points specified in data.csv into a `trisurf`

Comment: What can you tell us about the `data.csv` file? Is the data sorted in any particular way?

Comment: It does not have to be a trisurf, but I want to get smooth surface.

Comment: I have a data.ply which I converted into this csv file. The data are sorted based on contours. About 360 first lines in that file are the coordinates of the first contour and then next 360 lines are the coordinates of the second contour and so on. In the data.ply file each contour is separated by '*' char.

Comment: You may want to check the [delaunayn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunayn.html) and [tetramesh](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tetramesh.html) function

Comment: @gdlmx I checked those functions. When I tried the delaunayn function I get an error: "Undefined function 'delaunayTriangulation' for input arguments of type 'double'."
When I used the tetramesh It creates something similiar that I'm trying to get but the problem is that it is not hollow inside just like in the picture above.

Comment: You most likely need to use one of the [Volume Visualization](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/volume-visualization.html) functions rather than plain `surf`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your data: the surface that you want has 2 z-value for a certain x-y pair!

I cannot come up with a perfect solution, but you can try to cut the surface into two parts so that each part is a mono-value 2D function z=f(x,y)

```
% for the upper part, let's cut it by the plane z==0
X=X(Z>0);
Y=Y(Z>0);
Z=Z(Z>0);
```

And then run your code:

```
[XI YI ZI] = griddata(X,Y,Z,linspace(0,1),linspace(0,1)');
surf(XI,YI,ZI)
```

Plotting the lower part is similar. You can combine them in a single figure using `hold on`.

There is a more general discussion in the Matlab forum ["creating-3d-mesh-for-some-points-in-space"](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/62964-creating-3d-mesh-for-some-points-in-space)

Hopping it helps.

### Edited:

Here is the complete code, assuming your surface can be cut by the plane (z=0):

```
close all; clear all;
X=xlsread('data.csv', '', 'A:A');
Y=xlsread('data.csv', '', 'B:B');
Z=xlsread('data.csv', '', 'C:C');
[XI YI ZI] = griddata(X(Z>0),Y(Z>0),Z(Z>0),linspace(0,1),linspace(0,1)');
surf(XI,YI,ZI);
hold on;
[XI YI ZI] = griddata(X(Z<0),Y(Z<0),Z(Z<0),linspace(0,1),linspace(0,1)');
surf(XI,YI,ZI);
hold off;
```

Comment: Can you please write the whole code which I should use? I can't get it right

Comment: The key task is to create a mesh from scattered points. I am afraid there is no simple algorithm that works for all kinds of data. You need to write a sophisticated script to handle all kinds of subtle behaviors, which is time consuming. My suggestion is to go to a friend who can do that for you.